# ANSI C Bluetooth API and Tutorial Linux

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth

Is there a bluetooth API and tutorial for ANSI C in Linux?

Answer (score 6):

It obviously wouldn't be ANSI C but in Linux there is a great [Bluetooth stack](http://www.bluez.org/) that in junction with [D-BUS](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) let's you do great things with ease.

You can find [tutorials on their wiki](http://wiki.bluez.org/).

I hope you enjoy programming Bluetooth on Linux as much as I did.

Comment: Good C code should still compile when passed the -ansi flag, there will probably just be lots warnings. In any case, there's no reason why you can't write ansi C which uses a non-ansi compiled api.

Comment: Strictly speaking if you compile with -ansi flag it shouldn't compile if the code isn't trully ansi code. The "problem" with ansi is that it's designed to be easely portable and because of that the subset is very low level and not as complete as one might want.